# Load plugin in mongoose typescript model class

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to load plugin inside mongoSchema inside typescript its getting loaded but it always shows error. Like

[image]

So not able to build the api. The flow is like include the library for pagination:

[image]

After that I have interface for document

[image]

Then interface for model

[image]

and then created model class where i am using this method

[image]

Then i loaded the class and plugin also but the error is still there. Tried to place plugin load after schema but same error persist.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong.